# Проблема с работой yii2

Tags: yii

Здравствуйте. У меня установлен чистый Yii2 advanced-template.
При запуске тестовой команды:

> codecept run unit — -c backend ExampleTest

Получаю фатальную ошибку:

> Call to undefined method backend\tests\ExampleTest::setGroups() in /my/path/to/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php on line 229

Есть идеи, что пошло не так? 
Спасибо.

Comment: А вы смотрели `phpunit.xml`? Смотрели класс `backend\tests\ExampleTest`?

Comment: @korytoff, там всё хорошо, но тесты запустились с помощью команды: composer exec codecept run unit — -c backend